# Problem about probabilities of two car engine mounts breaking at the same time

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

An automobile engine has three independent mounts, their probabilities of breaking in a 10-year period are 0.2, 0.4, and 0.3, respectively. If the driver of the vehicle hears the characteristic noise of two broken mounts, determine the probability that mounts one and two are broken.

I have done problems like this one but never with this kind of question where you have to find the probability of two things breaking at the same time. Can someone help please?

Comment: This is obviously an exercise. Please share first what you have tried to do.

Comment: At best this problem is poorly stated. It says the mounts are independent - which could mean any number of different things physically. It does not say that the probability of them breaking is independent, which is of course what would be useful in solving it. If you are going to a crassly unrealistic assumption (the probability of real motor mounts on a single engine breaking is highly dependent), you should at least state it clearly. (This is a rant against the source of your problem - not against you personally.)

Comment: @KBS i tried to use bayes theorem to calculate de probability of mount A breaking and mount B breaking independently but i got stocked when the problem asks me to calculate the probability of both A and B breaking at the same time and not other combination of two mounts (C and B for example).

Comment: @PaulSinclair i think we can assume that the problem refers to the probability of each mount breaking is independent from the others.

Comment: I didn't deny that was the intent. I just pointed out that it is very poorly stated. A well-stated math problem does not force you to make assumptions beyond the standard conventions ("if the word 'independent' is used anywhere in the description, it means the events are independent" is not a standard convention). And it is particularly poorly stated if the assumption you need to make is a highly unrealistic one like this.

Comment: @PaulSinclair ok I understand what you mean, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm going to give it a try

We know that for sure two of the mounts are broken. We also know that the mounts breaking are independent of each other(at least that's what I gather from the problem's wording). Let events $A, B, C$ denote the respective breaking of the mounts:

$$P(A) = .2, P(B) = .4, P(C) = .3$$

Let's first find the probability that two mounts(and only two mounts) break:

$$P(\text{Two mounts break}) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap C) + P(B\cap C) - 3P(A\cap B\cap C)$$
Where the last term eliminates the probability that all three of them break because we have only heard two mounts break.

The question asks us for
$$P(A \cap B | \text{Two mounts break}) = \frac{P(\text{Two mounts break}|A \cap B)\times P(A \cap B)}{P(\text{Two mounts break})}$$
Where we can likely assume that $P(A \cap B) = .2 \times .3 = .06$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Alternatively: $\mathsf P(\text{Only two mounts break})=\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C^\complement)+\mathsf P(A\cap B^\complement\cap C)+\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B\cap C)$

Comment: @bigBear I think I understand how you solved the problem, thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @GrahamKemp yeah i think this is another way to look at it, thanks a lot.